# How to Create specific HTML forms automatically?

Tags: html, forms, automation

For my job, I have been put in charge of creating a Customer Satisfaction Survey; However, it is more complicated than one can guess. Our company works with several different clients, and with those clients, we have several different projects. So when I send out the survey to a specific client for a specific project somewhere on the survey it needs to tell them what the project is, the engineer, architect, and designer working on it is very complicated. Here's how I need it to look:

- A "Portal" on our website for us to enter the client data where it will then be processed and sent to the client invisibly. (This is only for our employees to see)
- A Processor that will process the data from the portal, automatically generate a form, then send a link to the client with the data.
- Another Processor that will process the data from the form and send it back to us and will*Also* show us the client data (designer, engineer,etc.)

Here is what I have so far:

- A Page on our site /create form with a basic form that takes the client data and is password protected so only we can see it. (No processor)
- A survey template
- An open window I can jump out of if things get hard

I am looking for some suggestions.

Comment: This is way, way beyond the scope of a question that should be asked on stack overflow. Questions should be specific, not requests for an entire tutorial. Based on the way you asked your question it sounds like you're in over your head and you should be looking to hire an actual web developer to do this.

Comment: Just looking for some suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Carter F I would look into using react for that style of system as it is modular and works great with a C# backend that talks to a sql database.

Comment: Thank you! Just looking for suggestions :)

Comment: @CarterF please can you select one as an answer please as this would help people who are also looking at the same thing Thanks